# Rails: cache.fetch vs cache.read/write

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

is there any performance difference between

```
Rails.cache.fetch("key") { Model.all }
```

and

```
models = Rails.cache.read("key")
if models.nil?
    models = Model.all
    Rails.cache.write("key", models)
end
```

If I must guess, i would say the upper one is just a shorthand for the other one.

Answer (score 25):

If you check [the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dd493d3b6f25147227db4c5d119d6b48c31f42e6/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L285), you'll notice that `fetch` does nothing more than call `read` and `write`.

Since it does some other operations (like checking if a block has been given, etc.) one could say that `fetch` is heavier, but I think it's totally negligible.

Comment: If it does both read and write then what is the point of caching?
It should write only if the data is updated, right?

Comment: @LunaLovegood `Rails.cache.fetch` does a read if you pass it a single argument and does a write if you pass in a block. See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching

Comment: When passed only a single argument, the key is fetched and value from the cache is returned. If a block is passed, that block will be executed **in the event of a cache miss**.